# Every Time I install dependencies in my react or node project it get installed at my terminal but not show in my package.json file

Tags: node.js, dependencies, npm-install, package.json

Every Time I install dependencies in my react or node project it get installed at my terminal but not show in my package.json file. What's wrong with my laptop's setting?

Answer (score 0):

I think you installed them in the wrong directory.
Close your text editor and open the folder of your project again and then try to install it again via the terminal of the text editor.
Otherwise, you can use the terminal of the laptop. cd into your project directory and install the dependencies.